# Get user input for a point position (x, y, z)

Tags: python

The position is in 3D.  So I need to get the user to input a point position for (x, y, z) and I need to ask the user to input three values three times for the three coordinates x, y, and z.

Would this be a correct way of going about this question?

```
x1 = int (input("Enter an x1 coordinate: "))
y1 = int (input("Enter an y1 coordinate: "))
z1 = int (input("Enter an z1 coordinate: "))
x2 = int (input("Enter an x2 coordinate: "))
y2 = int (input("Enter an y2 coordinate: "))
z2 = int (input("Enter an z2 coordinate: "))
x3 = int (input("Enter an x3 coordinate: "))
y3 = int (input("Enter an y3 coordinate: "))
z3 = int (input("Enter an z3 coordinate: "))
```

Or would I need to ask the user to input (x, y, z) all at once

```
plot 1 = int (input("coordinate(x, y, z): ")
```

Comment: You can do it either way, no? Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

```
plot1 = input("coordinate(x, y, z): ").split()
```

this will give you `["x","y","z"]`
now convert to int

```
plot1 = [int(i) for i in plot1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should write a method to get each vector as a list of 3 values, so you do not have to add and manually change another 3 lines of code in case you add another vector. Then you can still prompt the user to put the values in one by one, but the code would be much cleaner and flexible.

Example code:

```
AXES = ('x', 'y', 'z')

def input_vector(axes):
    values = []
    string = "Enter the coordinate of "
    for coord in axes:
        values.append(int(input(string + coord)))
    return values

vectors = []
for i in range(3):
    vectors.append(input_vector(AXES))
```